# Java server Stopped working on my computer, why?

Tags: java, localhost

I installed JIRA yesterday on my OSX computer. It worked by going to the address:

```
localhost:8080
```

I Turned off my computer yesterday, and today when I tried to go there, I got:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8080
```

No live server..

What is happening? How do i fix it?

Comment: Your JIRA server does not start automatically at reboot.
There should be instructions in the JIRA documentation on how to fix this...

Comment: thanks that worked. is there a way to make it start on boot?